# How is it possible that WinRar can repair any volume with any single one of .rev files?

Tags: winrar, ecc

There is already a similar question(and 2 solid answers), but mine is a little bit different.

Suppose you create a 5-volume archive + 3 recovery volumes(.rev files). This is supposed to reconstruct up to 3 of any of the original volumes. So far, so good.

But it also seems possible to reconstruct any one of the volumes even if you are missing any 2 of the 3 .rev files.

How is that possible?

IOW, how is it that **any** single one of those .rev files is sufficient to reconstruct **any** single one of the 5 volumes?

Answer (score 1):

The .rev files store the number of .rar files, the number of .rev files, the index of the .rev file, and the recovery data. WinRAR uses these values to determine the parameters for the recovery algorithm.

the math used makes sure that any combination of different files will have the same result.

[Math](http://blog.richardkiss.com/?p=264) (using matrices)